# Select option from dropdown to show one row of a table

Tags: excel, dropdown

Example of the table I have:

[image]

I want to create a spreadsheet that gives two dropdown menus, one for name and one for parameter. I want the user to select from A to F, which will then display `Name`, `ID`, `Occupation` and `Location` of the chosen selection. Then I want the user to be able to select from the `Parameter` column, but only for the specific row (i.e. if they select A, then the only options for the parameter dropdown menu would be A1-A5.) When they select the parameter they want, it will display the explanation. The final result will be everything from the row they selected being shown.

Is this possible in Excel?

I have tried inserting dropdowns, but they give a long list of all rows, when I just want the dropdown to display the six options A-F.

Comment: I want the final output to be the contents of the entire row, and the options in the dropdowns to be A-F, rather than AAAAAAAABBBBBBB etc.